# Subclass activity from a jar getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, manifest, classnotfoundexception

I have two Android projects. One is a library and compiles a jar the other an executable which includes this jar on the build path.

I'm subclassing an activity in the jar in my project but when I start it I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException.

Here's the manifest with the activity in question being `MainActivity`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.package.MyProject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my `MainActivity`, where the `QCARSamples` package is found in my jar:

```
package com.my.package.MyProject;

import java.io.File;

import com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.GraphicsEngineHook;
import com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.VuforiaTrackingActivity;

import com.my.package.MyProject.R;

public class MainActivity extends VuforiaTrackingActivity{
    private File blenderFile;

    @Override
    protected synchronized void updateApplicationStatus(final int appStatus){
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected GraphicsEngineHook getGraphicsEngineHook() {
        return new MyGraphicsEngineHook();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSplashScreenImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.splash_screen_image_targets;
    }
}
```

I also tried including the activity I'm subclassing in my manifest like so, but I was still getting the same error:

```
<activity>
    <android:name="com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.VuforiaTrackingActivity>
</activity>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As I see, in manifest you set yor package as `package="com.my.package.MyProject"`, but your activity in `com.my.package.Myproject`. Is it really different packages as My `P` roject and My `p` roject?

Comment: Sorry I changed the actual package name and typed that incorrectly, they are in fact the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is usually on the BuildPath.

Assuming you're using eclipse and ADT:
Right click on your project, select Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export and make sure that your library is selected.

Remember to clean the project before trying again.

it could also be the class path as the guy suggested on the commented, on the manifest, instead of editing direct the XML, go to the Application tab, select the activity, click Browser, uncheck 'Display classes from sources of Project ...', and select the Activity from your library.

Comment: +1 Exporting the library solved my first issue. I edited to include a new issue I'm getting about the libraries native code.

Comment: you should have created a new question with the new problem and marked my answer as the correct for the solved problem. That way other people could see your problem and the answer and solve their own problems.

Comment: Sorry, I thought they were somewhat related. I'll include the new question as a link in case someone else has issues with native code from their library too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993004/including-shared-objects-that-library-uses-in-android-project

Comment: Kind of interested though, why did I need to export the library? I've been reading that this only helps if another project were to depend on my project.

Comment: you don't have to export it. You can just mark it as library and reference it from you the App project.

Comment: I included the jar on the build path using Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries. Doing that alone without exporting the jar causes the issues I had. By "referencing it", do you mean doing (assuming you have the NDK plugin) Properties->Android->Add->PATH_TO_LIBRARY_IN_WORKSPACE? Because I tried that originally but was getting duplicate .so errors.

Comment: Okay, so I changed my makefile to not copy the .so and your way works also. It's strange that I don't see the .so files being copied to the libs directory of my Eclipse project when building, but they do appear in the apk when running, and there are no issues there. Now I see this may be a better alternative for libraries that we have the source code to and will be editing. Thanks!